# hosts in the web how to make sure host is not virtual

Tags: networking, virtual, global, host

(please redirect my question to relevant stack site, if I am in wrong place, however here I feel guaranteed to get help)

When playing with traceroute command I want to be sure I am not connecting to virtual host that may be dynamically mapped to a number of geographically dispersed servers(since it does not make much sense to track packets jumping from continents).

So more precisely with concrete example: how to prove with help of nslookup -querytype=NS google.com  that google may redirect me to different servers across the world. I tried IPconfig locator for all values returned by nslookup, it always returns same location: California Mountain View.

It seems I don't understand something really important in here. Thanks.

**update: tried nslook up from australian server, all the ip adresses still point to same location..**

Comment: Try nslookup from a different GEO, surely you'll get a different IP.

Comment: thanks, however I assume it has to be different country, how do I do that? I am trying to find hosts providing network tools however they get also redirected to California.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *prove* the location of any host.  At the very best you can make an educated guess.

- Geolocation databases are a big list of IP addresses and where the machines hosting those addresses are believed to be located.  But they are just a guess and even the best of them are only 90% accurate to the state/regional level, meaning 10% of the addresses are someplace completely different.  I use [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/) because they have a fairly accurate free version and their commercial versions are not too expensive.  They also have a free web-form where you can do 25 lookups per day.
- You can use tools like `traceroute` to see some of the machines between you and your destination.  Sometimes they have geographic locations in their DNS names.  Sometimes their IP addresses will be listed in Geolocation databases.  *However*, not all routers respond, many segments are virtualized and so their hops/routers are invisible, and firewalls may block the trace before it completes.
- DNS databases list the address of the organization who owns an address or domain.  DNS names themselves can be anything anyone wants, so even they contain geolocation information, there is no reason to believe it is true.  In particular, a router might have a DNS name indicating the destination its connecting to, or even the administrative office responsible for it, and not the physical location of the device itself.
- The IP address you are talking to can forward anything it wants to anywhere else it wants and there's absolutely no way you can detect that.  So you can only follow the trail up to a point.

To make a good guess for the location of a host, look-up its IP address in a geolocation database, then run a traceroute and look-up the IP address of the last router before the destination.  That will get you as close as you can.